# Julia Error - Constructor not found when defined

Tags: julia

Copied this into a jupyter notebook cell but can't get it to run and the message doesn't really help. Everything looks right.

```
mutable struct CircularArray{T} <: AbstractArray{T,1}
    data::Array{T,1}
    first::Int
    CircularArray{T}(length::Int) where {T} = new{T}(Array{T, 1}(undef, length), 1)
end

a = CircularArray(10)
MethodError: no method matching CircularArray(::Int64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is clear: you need to define `CircularArray(length::Int)`. What you implemented, however, is [a parametric constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Parametric-Constructors-1). To call your parametric constructor, you need to pass the parameter `T` with your constructor call, e.g.

```
a = CircularArray{Float64}(10);
```

You can also implement non-parametric constructor for a default type of your choice. For example;

```
CircularArray(length::Int) = CircularArray{Float64}(length)
```

After this your call to this constructor, `CircularArray(10);`, won't give a `MethodError: no method matching CircularArray(::Int64)`.

Note the `;` at the end of the commands. You need to define other methods (like `size`) for your array type so that `display` can work. Otherwise, you may get an error in REPL if you omit `;` after the evaluations that return a `CircularArray`.

Comment: I see, wouldn't it be helpful if it said the closest match was the parametric constructor?

Comment: @BAR I agree it would be helpful. However, the issue here is that `CircularArray`, `CircularArray{Float64}`, `CircularArray{Int64}`, and so on are different constructor *functions* so `CircularArray(::Int)`, `CircularArray{Float64}(::Int)`, `CircularArray{Int64}(::Int)` are not the *methods* of the same function. IIRC, the closest matches are found for the methods of the same function. That is why you do not see a more helpful error message.